# Is my Smart Contract Secure and Optimized properly?

Tags: solidity, security, optimization

how safe is this code and is it possible to optimize it

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

interface IBEP20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
}


contract TokenDistributerGBR {
    address[] public recipientsList;
    address public owner;
    IBEP20 public token;
    mapping(address => bool) public recipients;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
        _tokenAddress = 0xA970cAE9Fa1D7Cca913b7C19DF45BF33d55384A9;
        owner = msg.sender;
        token = IBEP20(_tokenAddress);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the contract owner can perform this action");
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "New owner cannot be the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    function addRecipient(address recipient) public onlyOwner {
        recipients[recipient] = true;
    }

    function removeRecipient(address recipient) public onlyOwner {
        recipients[recipient] = false;
    }

    function recipientsCount() public view returns (uint256 count) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipientsList.length; i++) {
            if (recipients[recipientsList[i]]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    function distributeTokens() public onlyOwner {
    require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= 1000000 * recipientsList.length, "Insufficient balance to distribute tokens");

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipientsList.length; i++) {
        if (recipientsList[i] != address(0)) {
            require(token.transfer(recipientsList[i], 1000000), "Token transfer failed");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems to be secure but here are a couple of things you can do to improve the overall efficiency of the smart contract

1. Remove the hardcoded _tokenAddress value from the constructor so it would look like this

```
constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        token = IBEP20(_tokenAddress);
    }
```

2. Add a recipientsCount variable to store the number of recipients instead of iterating over the entire `recipientsList` to count them. This can make the recipientsCount function more efficient.

```
uint256 public recipientsCount;

function distributeTokens() public onlyOwner {
        require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= 1000000 * recipientsCount, "Insufficient balance to distribute tokens");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipientsList.length; i++) {
            if (recipients[recipientsList[i]]) {
                require(token.transfer(recipientsList[i], 1000000), "Token transfer failed");
            }
        }
```

Additionally, same variable will also be used in below 2 functions from point 3.

3. Modify the `addRecipient` and `removeRecipient` functions to check if the recipient is already added or removed before updating the recipients mapping and `recipientsCount` variable to avoid unnecessary gas costs. The updated code should look like this

```
function addRecipient(address recipient) public onlyOwner {
        if (!recipients[recipient]) {
            recipients[recipient] = true;
            recipientsCount++;
        }
    }

    function removeRecipient(address recipient) public onlyOwner {
        if (recipients[recipient]) {
            recipients[recipient] = false;
            recipientsCount--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the good advice, but could you give an example of the code that implements point two from your answer?

Comment: @LllCilician check updated answer! I missed that part earlier